# Delete specific Key from Dictionary into another Dictionary - C#

Tags: c#

I have this example of dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<Configs>>> dict_of_all_configs 
  = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<Configs>>>();
```

Now i want delete some item from the second dictionary, i know the 1ºKey(parentNode), 2ºKey(childNode):

```
public void DeleteSelectedConfig(bool parentNodeSelect, string parentNode, string childNode)
{
  if ( parentNodeSelect )
    dict_of_all_configs.Remove(parentNode);
  else
  {
    //Dont work it:
    dict_of_all_configs.Remove(dict_of_all_configs[parentNode][int.Parse(childNode)][0].ToString());

    //dict_of_all_configs.Where(pair => pair.Key == parentNode).Select(pair =>
    //{
    //    dict_of_all_configs.Remove(pair.Key);
    //    return pair.Key;
    //});
  }
```

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Are the parent/child nodes you specify *guaranteed* to be in the dictionary? If so, can you just do `dict_of_all_configs[parentNode].Remove(int.Parse(childNode))`?

Comment: Nested dict can be expressed as "flat" if you (ab)use Touple as key, which could simplify your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove a key value pair from the nested dictionary, given the key of the nested dictionary (`parentNode`) and the key you want removed (`childNode`).

You can do it like this (assuming the keys exist):

```
dict_of_all_configs[parentNode].Remove(int.Parse(childNode));
```

`dict_of_all_configs[parentNode]` gives you the nested dictionary, which is the dictionary from which you want to `.Remove(...)` a key. You should not call `.Remove` on `dict_of_all_configs` directly, because you don't want any keys to be removed from the outer dictionary.

Comment: After seeing your answer it all makes sense, how could I not see this.
Thank you very much!